# Nsuserdefaults remove value and key

Tags: swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults, swift3

I want to know how to remove both key and value in NSUserDefaults . removeobjectforkey only removes the value ?

```
removeObjectForKey(string)
```

Comment: That's all you need, if you remove the object for your key, the key is automatically removed. BTW the correct syntax Swift 3 would be `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "yourKey")`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**
to add value in NSUserDefault

integer

```
 UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "key")
```

a dictionary

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Dictvariable, forKey: "key")
```

get value
from integer

```
key value = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "key")
```

get value from dictionary

```
let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "key") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]()
```

to remove(i not tried this u can try this take it from stackoverflow 99% its work)

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "yourKey")
```